# N subset of cardinal number N/2 with minimum pairwise cardinal number of intersections

Tags: cardinals

Given a universe U of cardinal number N find N subsets of cardinal number N/2 that cover U so as to minimize the cardinal number of **pairwise** intersections between subsets. **We assume N is even**.

Example:
U = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Subsets:

```
{1, 2, 3}
{3, 4, 5}
{2, 4, 6}
{4, 5, 6}
{1, 5, 6}
{2, 3, 6}
```

Pairwise Intersections:

```
{1, 2, 3} ^ {3, 4, 5} = {3}
{1, 2, 3} ^ {2, 4, 6} = {2}
{1, 2, 3} ^ {4, 5, 6} = {}
{1, 2, 3} ^ {1, 5, 6} = {1}
{1, 2, 3} ^ {2, 3, 6} = {2, 3}
{3, 4, 5} ^ {2, 4, 6} = {4}
{3, 4, 5} ^ {4, 5, 6} = {4, 5}
{3, 4, 5} ^ {1, 5, 6} = {5}
{3, 4, 5} ^ {2, 3, 6} = {3}
{2, 4, 6} ^ {1, 5, 6} = {6}
{2, 4, 6} ^ {2, 3, 6} = {2, 6}
{4, 5, 6} ^ {1, 5, 6} = {5, 6}
{4, 5, 6} ^ {2, 3, 6} = {6}
{1, 5, 6} ^ {2, 3, 6} = {6}
```

The cardinal number of all pairwise intersections is at most 2. I would like to get a lower value than 2 and in general, find a method to select the subsets so as to minimize the cardinal number of the pairwise intersections.

Comment: In your example it looks like you missed $\{2,4,6\}\cap \{4,5,6\}$.

Comment: Are you interested in minimizing the total sum of the sizes of all the intersections; or only in minimizing the size of the largest intersection?

Comment: @paw88789 The size of the largest intersection.

Comment: @paw88789 {2,4,6}∩{4,5,6} is missing indeed